# Cross Field Validation in MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to accomplish some cross field validation in MVC 5. Specifically, if a check box is checked a free form response area, which is normally optional, is then required. Server side seems to be working correctly, but I cant get my Client side validation to work.

Working from other solutions out there here is my RequiredIfAttribute Class and Validator

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute{
public string DependentUpon { get; set; }
public string CallerValue { get; set; }

public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentUpon)
{
    this.DependentUpon = dependentUpon;
    //this.Value = null;
}

protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    object instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    var property = type.GetProperty(DependentUpon);
    var targetValue = property.GetValue(instance);

    if (value == null)
        CallerValue = "";
    else
        CallerValue = value.ToString();

    if(Convert.ToBoolean(targetValue) == true && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CallerValue))
        return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}}

public class RequiredIfValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<RequiredIfAttribute>{
public RequiredIfValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RequiredIfAttribute attribute)
    : base(metadata, context, attribute)
{ }

public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
{
    var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        ValidationType = "requiredifvalidation",
        ErrorMessage = Attribute.FormatErrorMessage(Metadata.PropertyName),
    };

    rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentupon", Attribute.DependentUpon);

    return new[] { rule };
}}
```

I have my Global.asax register

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter( typeof(RequiredIfAttribute), typeof(RequiredIfValidator));
```

Tag to my metadata

```
    [StringLength(1000)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Investigator Notes")]
    [RequiredIf("NotToBeProcessed")]
    public string InvestigatorNotes { get; set; }
```

and some JS from an older post to try and propagate the Validation to the Client side

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredifvalidation", function (value, element, params) {
if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
}

var dependentUponControl = $("#" + params.dependentUpon);
if (dependentUponControl == null) {
    return false;
}

var dependentUponValue = dependentUponControl[0].value;
return dependentUponValue == value;});

function testConditionEqual(element, params) {
/* Find control for other property */
var dependentUponControl = $("#" + params.dependentUpon);
if (dependentUponControl == null) {
    return false;
}

var dependentUponValue;
if (dependentUponControl[0].type == "checkbox") {
    dependentUponValue = (dependentUponControl[0].checked) ? "True" : "False";
} else {
    dependentUponValue = dependentUponControl[0].value;
}

return dependentUponValue == params.comparand;}
```

Server Side validation applies and will not pass the model to be saved when the form is filled out and reloads the page, but my form page never updates displays the Validation in my

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvestigatorNotes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

area

Comment: Have you considered using the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` validation attribute?

Comment: I have, but I had issues with it working with entity framework, and online it says its still in beta. Between the two, I figured I would go with my own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RequiredIf attribute from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1924941.aspx?Conditional%20Validation%20using%20DataAnnotation) before. Works pretty well. It has server-side and client code, and the usage is exactly the same as yours:

```
public class Category 
{     
    [RequiredIf("IsActive", true)]     
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried it, but I'm getting an error: "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference"  All I did was copy over the code, then changed my metadata to use the new class and when I submit my form I get the error.

Comment: I fixed that error by changing the control.attr('checked').toString(); to control.is(':checked').toString(), but again the validation doesn't show on the page... My form submits and is kicked back by the controller's server side validation

Comment: I fixed that  issue too, but alas, still not working with that solution. return $.validator.methods[rule].call(this, value, element, ruleparam); throws an error because $.validator is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: So.. After a little research I realized that MVC, out of the box, does not add the script files for validation to your layout page.. Meaning, my Validator was never defined! I've been working with different solutions for a week and that is probably the reason none worked.